# Live stream laptop screen to TV via LAN?

Tags: windows-8, tv

I have OBS which can stream my computers monitor to the internet but I need to setup a server that will let my TV, iPod, etc. connect to it to view the screen. I'm trying to achieve the lowest delay possible. How would I go along with such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is HDMI over Ethernet, that's for the TV, as for the iPod, Stream it over using some streaming protocol and receive the stream on the iPod, if you do that, you can also watch it on the TV using a raspberry pi.